# KeyError in While Loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, python-2.6

I am trying to loop through pagination URLs. I find the pagination URL on the first page, go to it, find it on the 2nd page, go to it, so on until the last page. However, I get a KeyError which is a result of pagination being absent from the last page. However, I thought my equation would catch that since my statement would then be false and the loop stops.

```
response1 = requests.get("api.weather.gov/alerts?limit=100") # request API
data1 = response1.json()
pag_object1 = (data1['pagination']['next']) #find pagination object 

while ("pagination" in str(data1)) == True: # while string is found
    response1 = requests.get(pag_object1) # use 1st pag object to make new response
    data1 = response1.json()
    pag_object1 = (data1['pagination']['next']) # redefine pag object
```

**Error:**

```
KeyError: 'pagination'
```

Comment: Why are you checking if it's in `str(data1)` instead of checking whether it's in `data1`? By converting the dict to a string representation, and then doing a substring match, you'll match things like `{'something': 'i have no pagination'}`. But then, `data1['pagination']` will of course fail.

Comment: `data1 = response1.json()` overwrites `data1` with a new dict...

Comment: @abarnert yes, but it works at line 3. OP overwrites `data1` with something else in the loop. and the test comes too late.

Comment: Without seeing the actual contents of your `data1` object, i can't know for sure what's happening, but I suppose that `data1`'s representation as a string contains the string "pagination" somewhere, without data1 actually containing the "pagination" key. You should change your test to `while "pagination" in data1:`

Comment: @bsam That still gives the same error.

Comment: of course it does. This isn't the real issue. Only part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive the problem is the following, you redefine the pag_object1 before the condition of the while loop is checked again.

What I belive is happening:

- data1 is the 2nd last page and still contains the 'pagination' object
- pag_object1 can be assigned as data1 contains a key called 'pagination'
- while condition will evaluate to True

Last Loop:

- data1 is on the last page and doesn't contain the key 'pagination' but you nevertheless try to assign the pag_object1 before you check the condition of the while loop

This should fix it:

```
response1 = requests.get("api.weather.gov/alerts?limit=100") # request API
data1 = response1.json()

# while the pagination string is in the keys 
while "pagination" in data1: 
    # assign the pagination object
    pag_object1 = (data1['pagination']['next']) 

    # use pag_object1 to create a new request for the next page
    response1 = requests.get(pag_object1) 

    # assign the new page to the data1 object
    data1 = response1.json()
```

Comment: `while ("pagination" in data1.keys()) == True: ` => `while "pagination" in data1: `

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: cool, thanks! I missed that. 
Is using keys() better or worse coding style-wise? It's more verbose / explicit.

Comment: python 2: keys returns a list, and lookup is `O(n)`: missing the point of a dictionary...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: @meck Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew I didn't have the order of my definitions correct. Your response explains it in a way I couldn't!